# What are the essential tools and proof techniques for beginning smooth manifolds and differential topology?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, problem-solving, smooth-manifolds

I am an undergraduate currently taking a first course in smooth manifolds. I feel that I understand the material intuitively. But, I'm having trouble turning my intuition into proofs. I was hoping that I could get answers to the two following questions:

- What are the essential basic tactics for attacking smooth manifold and differential topology problems?
- What are the best things to do to improve my technique and ability to solve problems?

Let me give an example of what I mean. [I just asked another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1788212/given-p-in-sn-1-how-does-one-show-that-the-map-pi-so-n-to-sn-1-by) about showing a particular map is a submersion. I have an intuitive understanding of what is going on. In the context of the problem, I can see what is happening in the case $\pi: SO_3 \to S^2$. The idea is that if I look at a point on a sphere, and I look at the directions coming off of that point, there is a rotation of the sphere that moves it in that direction. For instance, if I'm looking at a point on the equator, there is a rotation that moves the point northward, and a rotation that moves it westward, and that's enough to show I can move the point in any direction I like.

But, turning that into a proof is a little bit of a daunting task. So daunting, in fact, I was compelled to ask about it. When I asked my professor about this problem, he drew me a picture and explained the intuition. I think intuition is important, but what I'm having trouble with it turning my intuition into a proof. The reason I'm having trouble with that is I don't exactly know what the essential proof techniques are. So, I firstly want to know what these proof techniques are, and secondly want to know what I can do to be acquainted with their use.

I feel I should clarify what I'm saying somewhat. When I say tools here, I mean something along the lines of "use Sard's theorem" or "partitions of unity." For example, I would say that using the regular level set theorem, instead of constructing charts, to show that some set is a manifold is a tool. I understand that showing something is s submersion requires showing its differential is surjective, that being the definition of the term. What I mean is, what are good ways to exploit the structure I have? What are the proof techniques unique to this structure?

Comment: The first step is always to write down the definitions of any mathematical terms.  This will tell you what is it that you are ultimately going to have to show.  Then you can think about how it is that you are going to get there.

Comment: You need to understand the language and mathematics of linear algebra and multivariable calculus. Any statement about "submersions" is translatable into that language and proved using that mathematics.